# Redirect after file download

Tags: php, http-headers

My problem is:

Pressing a link on my page will (through the referred php file) call a function which downloads a file from my webservice. This means that header information is send upon file download, which also means that I'm not able to call the php header function to redirect BACK to my initial page where I clicked the link in the beginning. The reason WHY I want togo back to that page is that it will update my history of latest downloaded files, but not before the file is downloaded.

What is the BEST way to overcome this obstacle?

My function which initiates the download:

```
public function downloadAuthorityRules($api_key,$id)
{

    $curl_post_data = array('id' => $id); 

    $headers = array('Content-type: application/json','Authorization: '.$api_key,);
    $fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/localfile.tmp', 'w+');//This is the file where we save the    information
    $curl = curl_init(DOWNLOAD_AUTHORITYRULES);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($curl_post_data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_key);
    $file = curl_exec($curl);

    if ($file === false) 
    {
        $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
    }

    curl_close($curl);

    header('Content-type: ' . 'application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: ' . 'attachment; filename=myndighedsregler.pdf');
    echo $file;        
}
```

Comment: Why redirect? If you have a script serving up the downloaded data, have that script update the download stats before it starts spitting out the bytes.

Comment: In addition to what Marc B said, if you set your headers immediately as a download the site will not navigate away from the current page- which means they shouldn't ever leave the page, thus no need to go back.

Comment: The function called on my webservice will update the tables involved with the download. I cannot request the status of the downloaded files from my webservice before the download has actually been executed and the involved tables updated.

Comment: Further info on the last two comments: The page MUST be reloaded in order to call the webservice to query the updated download history after my download has finished (tables updated)

Comment: Im wondering why people DOWN-VOTE questions without leaving a comment why. Does my question need further explanation ?. It strikes me as rather unconstructive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot redirect from the download page after download completes. Its just not possible.

You will need to update the db table in the download page *before* you begin serving the file.  Then your homepage that displays the download history will update naturally when its refreshed next (assuming you set no-cache headers properly).

Yes, I know, you want to force it to update. But you can't do it the way you were thinking.

> What is the BEST way to overcome this obstacle?

You could do Ajax polling from the homepage to refresh the insides of a certain DIV every so many seconds. You will need to make sure to set `cache: false` in your `$.ajax()` call (if using jQuery, which I would recommend you do for Ajax). Otherwise, the info on the homepage might not pull the new data due to the browser caching Ajax results.

Answer (score 1):

Found another way of solving my redirect problem, which could be of use to others:

My webpage currently uses AJAX to load content into my DIV'S, thus i already have a javascript function called loadPage.

What i did, was to implement a function called delayedLoadPage, which simply uses setTimeout as follows

```
function delayedLoadPage(page)
{
    setTimeout(function() { loadPage(page);},5000);     
}
```

This function will simply call the loadPage after 5 seconds have past.

I changed my  where my reference to the php which does the download is located and added an onclick event

```
<a onclick="javascript:delayedLoadPage('authorityRules.php')" href="<? echo "downloadAuthorityRules.php?id=".$auth_current['auth_rules'][0]['id'];?>" >
```

The result is, that the file will start to download, and 5 seconds later my page is reloaded when the timeout occures and loadPage is called.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the hardcoded timeout and to reload the page after the download has started / the download prompt appeared? Because maybe the the download needs significantly more or less time than 5 seconds.